# SOQL Aggregate query for related opportunity

Tags: soql, aggregate, aggregateresult

I want to use accounts and related Opportunities in my LWC.

```
@AuraEnabled(Cacheable=true)
    public static Account[] getAllAccounts(){
        return [SELECT 
                    Id,
                    Name,
                    (SELECT 
                        Id,
                        Name,
                        CreatedDate,
                        CloseDate,
                        Amount
                    FROM Opportunities)
                FROM Account
                WHERE Opportunities.StageName = 'Closed Won'
                WITH SECURITY_ENFORCED
                GROUP BY Name
                ];
    }
```

The problem is that I want to use SUM(Amount) Related to each account but I can't find how to do that. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to make easier. It's just needed to create custom roll-up summary field and retrieve it from apex.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can aggregate the value of fields on child records using SOQL alone.

You can alternatively try use Opportunity as your source object like this:

```
List<AggregateResult> result = [SELECT AccountId, SUM(Amount) FROM Opportunity GROUP BY AccountId];
```

Then parse the results into a map or something, however you need to deal with the data, for example:

```
Map<Id, Decimal> mappedResults = new Map<Id, Decimal>();
for (Integer i = 0; i < results.size(); ++i) {
    mappedResults.put(Id.valueOf(String.valueOf(results[i].get('AccountId'))), Double.valueOf(results[i].get('expr0')));
}
```

Then you'd have a map like this:

```
{0018E00001hc9eJXXX => 5.0, 0018E00001hp4VdYYY => 9.0}
```

Hopefully this is somewhat helpful, until someone can provide what you're looking for!